# How to label url in latex?

Tags: hyperref, urls, links

I am trying to include an url with a label so something like that: [GOOGLE](http://google.ru)
I am writing this

```
\hypperef[mylabel]{myurl}
```

or this

```
\url[mylabel]{myurl}
```

and compiler gives me an error what am I doing wrong? I am using both required packages

Comment: Can you please add a minimal working example? That is, the shortest complete LaTeX document that demonstrates this problem?

Comment: `\href{myurl}{mylabel}`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just need to customise the formatting `hyperref` uses. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}        
\begin{document}
  \href{http://google.ru/}{GOOGLE}
\end{document}
```

[image: coloured link]